# Any idea on how to create a glossary in an R shiny App?

Tags: r, shiny, glossary

I already looked into the R shiny app gallery but couldn't find a fitting example. I found an R package for creating an FAQ page but that's not exactly what I want. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does an html "accordion" fit what you want? If so, [`"r" "shiny" "accordion"`](https://www.google.com/search?q="r"+"shiny"+"accordion") revealed https://rinterface.github.io/shinydashboardPlus/articles/extra-elements.html, which might fit your needs. Outside of that, though, this question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) since it is asking us to *"recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource"*. If you can make it a question about a coding problem, please do, otherwise it will likely be closed. (Interesting question, though.)

Comment: Oh thanks, @r2evans! I will have a closer look at it, at a first glance it looks interesting! Sure, that is not question on coding, sorry for that and again thanks for the link :)!